# Loading error Magento 2 site frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, page, home-page

I am facing a issue in making Magento 2 store, once a page is loaded it works fine but after refreshing the same page it gets stuck and doesn't work properly. here I attach the reference images:

Here is the link to site : http://www.i-ranu.com/
_/_ any help to solve this issue is highly appreciated _/_

**Loading for once this is preview**
[image]

**Refreshing the page this is preview**
[image]

Every time cache is cleared page loads without any issue (Kindly help).

Comment: It's working fine, there is no issue. Provide more details to reproduce error

Comment: sir, when site is refreshed 2-3 times slider stops automatically and works once cache of browser is cleared